# How to avoid a for-loop when creating several UI elements based on user input (a vector) in shiny R

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to avoid the infamous for-loop in my shiny app, but so far I have not been able to find a solution. This is my first *real* shiny project, any input is gladly appreciated.

My scenario is: The user provides a data frame. The app then generates a drop-down menu for every column. *(Later this will be used to decide whether the column should be treated as factor, co-variate or disregarded in a linear model)*

My current approach is to use a for-loop and the insertUI-function:

**ui.R:**

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    actionButton("ADD","ADD")
  )
)
```

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
opts <- c("A","B")
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  for(i in 1:length(mtcars)){
  insertUI(
        selector = "#ADD",
        where="afterEnd",
      ui=selectInput(paste(names(mtcars[i]),"sel"),names(mtcars[i]),opts)
      )
      }
})
```

This works but it does not feel elegant at all. 
Thanks for your input on how I could improve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go the route of using `lapply` and wrapping the result in `tagList` to create a collection of selectors.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

shinyApp(
  ui = 
    shinyUI(
      fluidPage(
        selectInput(inputId = "data",
                    label = "Select a dataset",
                    choices = c("mtcars", "iris")),
        uiOutput("select_control")
      )
    ),

  server = 
    shinyServer(function(input, output, session){

      dataset <- eventReactive(input$data,
                               get(input$data))


      output$select_control <- 
        renderUI({
          tagList(
            lapply(names(dataset()),
                   function(x)
                   {
                     selectInput(inputId = sprintf("select_control_%s",
                                                   x),
                                 label = x,
                                 choices = unique(dataset()[[x]]))
                   }
            )
          )
        })
    })
)
```

Comment: Is there any reason you have attached ggplot2 in your example?

Comment: I had originally intended to inclue the `mpg` dataset in the app. Apparently I forgot/changed my mind.